# Move term set under term set

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, term-store, term-set, managed-metadata-service

Is it possible to move a term set under another term set? In the admin it seems to be possible to move a term set from term group to term group, but not (in this example) to move job title under department.

[image: Term set]

Comment: As far as I'm aware of, you can only move a term set to a new group and terms to a new term set.